# Click the cell on tableview will display view (not child cell) in other storyboard like expandable list swift ios

Tags: ios, tableview, cell, expandable

I have tableView in view controller. I want to do when click the cell on the tableView, it will expand show the view (label, button in other storyboard). I see the tutorial it will show other sub cell when expand. But i want it show the view. I already can make when user click row it will open new view. But now i want it will show in the same page without popup to new page. I newbie in swift ios.

for example, I want to do like this image. When click row, it will show view -

[image]

Comment: Please add some more description, I can't understand what are you trying to do. If you want some expandable tableview functionality then you have to add new uitableviewcell and If you want to show another view OR popup on table cell selection then simply use didSelectionRowAtIndex delegate of tableview and show your view OR popup.

Comment: Yes, i already make when click row (didSelectionRowAtIndex) , it will popup other view .. but now what i want to do is when click row (didSelectionRowAtIndex), it will show view in the same page.

Comment: Then simple design a custom view programmatically or using xib and show that custom view on row selection.

Comment: i use View controller in storyboard. when click on the row , it will show this view controller in the same page without open to new page. (like expandable list). When click on the row again, it will close the view

Comment: before this i do when click on the row, it open new page. then click back button.

Comment: show us some code please what are you doing.

Comment: self.parent?.navigationController?.pushViewController(levelController, animated: true) 

before this i use this code to open new viewcontroller

Comment: When did you push your levelController?

Comment: in didselectedrow